# How can I hide and show rows in my table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a table where my rows have classes:

```
<table id="abc">
<tr class="level-0">
<tr class="level-1">
<tr class="level-2">
</table>
```

I need to create two buttons.

- [Hide level 1 and 2] - when clicks this hides or shows all the
  level-2 rows.
- [Hide level 2] - when clicks this hides or shows the level-1 and level-2 rows.

Can someone tell me how I can implement this with jQuery?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `click` event handler and `toggle` function (for description check [jquery API](http://api.jquery.com)):

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    // all trs with level-1 class inside abc table
    $('#abc tr.level-1').toggle();
});

$('#button1and2').click(function() {
    // all trs with level-1 or level-2 class inside abc table
    $('#abc tr.level-1, #abc tr.level-2').toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/73JAV/

Comment: That won't work the way you have it - make a fiddle and demonstrate, please; also you're re-querying the dom for the inside of both click handlers which is unnecessary overhead.

Comment: Well I've added fiddle and it works, though OP didn't exacly specifed how it should behave : "hide or show", so it sounds like `toggle` to me.

Comment: About "unnecessary overhead": nobody seems to care too much about it (check other answers...) because it is not the point of question (unless specified). It is up to OP to work it out, because she/he is the only one to know full code structure.

Comment: You're free to disagree with my comment; just pointing out that your proposed solution at the time of my downvote was not working. I fiddled it and you edited subsequent to that. Apologies if you took offense; I think a 3-line, concise, solution that does not re-query the DOM unnecessarily is the always the best route.

Comment: @philwinkle sure thing. I've added fiddle, but my answer remained unchanged ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use a click and the `next()` function:

http://jsfiddle.net/Ah7Dm/

```
$('.level-1').click(function(){
  $(this).next('.level-2').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#button1').click(function(){
        $('#level0').hide('slow');  
        $('#level0').hide('slow');  
        ...
    });

    $('#button2').click(function(){
        $('#level0').show('slow');  
        $('#level0').show('slow');  
        ...
    });         
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" >
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('#level_1_2').click(function(){
                $('.level-2').toggle();
            });
            $('#level_2').click(function(){
                if(jQuery('.level-1').is(':visible')){
                    $('.level-2').show();
                }else{
                    $('.level-2').hide();
                }
                $('.level-2 , .level-1').toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="level_1_2" value="Hide level 1 and 2">
    <input type="button" id="level_2" value="Hide level 2">
    <table id="abc">
    <tr class="level-0"><td>0</td></tr>
    <tr class="level-1"><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr class="level-2"><td>2</td></tr>
    </table> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem where next level is child of previous tr.

```
`<table>
<tbody>
 <tr class="level-1"></tr>
 <tr class="level-2"></tr> 
 <tr class="level-3"></tr>
 <tr class="level-4"></tr>
 <tr class="level-4"></tr>
 <tr class="level-2"></tr>
 <tr class="level-2"></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

So far i have

```
$('table tbody .level-1').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var current_tr_class = $(this).parent().attr('class');
        next_tr_class = parseInt(current_tr_class.replace ( /[^\d.]/g, '' ))+1; // get last increase by 1 it is 1 make it 2

        $('tr.level-'+next_tr_class).toggle({ opacity: "toggle" }); // Open toggle2
        });
```

I hope this could solve your problem but not mine i have all dynamically generated. and if you click on level-1 it will untoggle all the element with level-2 even if it is after level-4. but level-4 will be still hide and it will be like loop.

Comment: I have the same requirement you do where every odd row is detail that I want to be expanded when the row above is clicked. I found this nice little jQuery plugin. Very simple code: http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/expand-table-rows-with-jquery-jexpand-plugin/